# Want to print email on the default android drawer but getting some "Closure()" error

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

**Want to Print Account Email ID on the Drawer ** 
I am building a Flutter application and I am facing issues to parse the user's Email ID from the Google Sign-In Method, my app Does Sign in Well using Google Sign in but I am unable to access the user data from user.email function I tried using different Future async Function but I am still stuck there.

Please Find a possible way to Guide my problem, Note: I have tried searching the Web and tried almost all the possible sources

```
class _ExtendedHomeState extends State<ExtendedHome> {
final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
  accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
  idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
);
final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;
assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);
final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
email = user.email;
imageUrl = user.photoUrl;
return email;
 }
 printEmail() async
  {
signInWithGoogle();
String email = await signInWithGoogle();
print(email);
return email;
  }
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context)
   {
   return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: DefaultTabController(length: 2,
   child: Scaffold(
     drawer: Drawer(
       elevation: 16.0,
       child: ListView(
         children: <Widget>[
           UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
             accountEmail: Text('$printEmail,', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),),
           ),
         ],
       ),
     ),
```

Please suggest any other method if possible
Tried all methods Available but Was unsuccessful

[image: wanted to print the email in place of "Closure() => dynamic from function 'printEmail'"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing an async function there, that's why it's showing you the type of that function. If you want to print the result getting back from an async function, you can use a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html):

```
accountEmail: FutureBuilder<String>(
     future: printEmail(),
     builder: (context, snapShot) {
       if (snapShot.hasData) {
       return Text(snapShot.data, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),);
       } else {
         return Text('Loading');
       }
     }),
```

Also change your function signature to:

```
Future<String> printEmail() async {
  // Your existing code
}
```

Comment: okay another simple question, if you can help with, I want to use  the google user's existing profile image on the circle avatar given over there,

Comment: @SomsubroBanerjee You can use NetworkImage widget to load images from web-url.

Comment: no no actually i want to use the google's profile pic in my app when they sign in like other apps in the playstore does, when you sign in with your account and the app automatically gets your user profile pic on the circle avatar get it?

Comment: @SomsubroBanerjee So what's your question ? You'll get the google profile image. In the user object, there is a property called photoUrl, which you can use to get the profile image.

Comment: yes i want to use the photoUrl method  but i can't use it with futurebuilder or use any other relavent function

Comment: @SomsubroBanerjee Please ask clearly, I'm still not understanding what is the issue. Why you need to use futurebuilder for that photo ? why can't you just use the networkimage widget and pass that url to get the image ?

Comment: i am facing trouble calling photoUrl using the currentUser() method, just help me with that

Comment: this is what i get The getter 'photoUrl' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: photoUrl

Comment: You do a condition in your widget binding code currentUser == null ? show dummy image : show profile image. When user logs in set the currentUser in a setState